# Calculate an expression at specific array positions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays `dQ/dx` and `dQ/dt` and I want to calculate `V = (dQ/dt)/(dQ/dx)` but only at the positions where both `dQ/dx` and `dQ/dt` are nonzero. If `dQ/dx` or `dQ/dt` are equal to zero then `V = 0`. In example `dQ/dx = [ 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1]`, `dQ/dt = [0.1 , 0 , 0.4 , 0]`, which should give `V = [0, 0, 2, 0]`.
I could do that with a loop over all array elements but is there a more "NumPy" way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is a possible way to go:

```py
In [216]: import numpy as np

In [217]: dQdx = np.asarray([0, 0, 0.2, 0.1])

In [218]: dQdt = np.asarray([0.1 , 0, 0.4, 0])

In [219]: V = np.where(np.logical_and(dQdt, dQdx), dQdt/dQdx, 0)
<ipython-input-219-6cd6dde99502>:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  V = np.where(np.logical_and(dQdt, dQdx), dQdt/dQdx, 0)
<ipython-input-219-6cd6dde99502>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  V = np.where(np.logical_and(dQdt, dQdx), dQdt/dQdx, 0)

In [220]: V
Out[220]: array([0., 0., 2., 0.])
```

There are different methods to get rid of this ugly `RuntimeWarning`. For example, you could index the entries that are nonzero in both arrays through advanced indexing using the Boolean array `np.logical_and(dQdt, dQdx)` like this:

```py
In [221]: V = np.zeros_like(dQdx)

In [222]: idx = np.logical_and(dQdt, dQdx)

In [223]: V[idx] = dQdt[idx]/dQdx[idx]

In [224]: V
Out[224]: array([0., 0., 2., 0.])
```